# x-axis labels do not match bars

Tags: r

Hello I am trying to create a stacked barplot using the following code:

```
test <- as.matrix(read.csv(file="test4.csv",sep=",",head=TRUE))
test <- test[,2:ncol(test)]
pdf(file="test.pdf", height=4, width=6)
par(lwd = 0.3)
barplot(test, space=0.4, xaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
axis(1, cex.axis=0.25, las=2, at=1:ncol(test), space=0.4, labels=colnames(test))
dev.off()
```

And I get:
[image]

As you can see the labels in the x-axis do not match the bars in the plot. Also, the ticks are huge.
Can you guys help me beautify the x axis? Thanks so much

Comment: Honestly, I can't read the labels on the x-axis, so I have no idea what they're supposed to match or not match.

Comment: Sorry, here is a bigger version. Ill keep trying to get a bigger and clearer version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try storing the returned value of the call to `barplot()` in a named object, and then passing that in to the `at=` argument of `axis()`:

```
xLabLocs <- barplot(test, space=0.4, xaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
axis(1, cex.axis=0.25, las=2, at=xLabLocs, 
     space=0.4, labels=colnames(test))
```

This may look odd, but it is explained in the `Value` section of the `?barplot` help file:

> ```
> Value:
>      A numeric vector (or matrix, when ‘beside = TRUE’), say ‘mp’,
>      giving the coordinates of _all_ the bar midpoints drawn, useful
>      for adding to the graph.
> ```

You just made the (easy enough to make) mistake of assuming that the x-axis coordinates of the bar centers are at 1:n, where n is the number of bars. That's not necessarily true, so it's nice that a single call to `barplot()` will both: (a) plot the bar plot as its side effect; and (b) return the necessary x-axis coordinates as its return value.

Comment: Indeed, Thanks so much. Now is it me or the y axis is quite far from the plot?

Comment: If you think so, you can first suppress the plotting of *both* axes, via `barplot(..., axes=FALSE)`, and then better position the y-axis using the `pos=` argument to `axis()`. (`axis(2, pos=0.3)` will move the y-axis a bit to the right of its default location.)